Problems with Executing PHPUnit/Pest Unit and Feature Tests in CI/CD Pipeline Testing
I'm currently conducting CI/CD testing via GitHub Actions and ran into a snag while executing tests. I'm working on a Laravel project, leveraging Breeze for authentication. The problem arises in the test_login_screen_can_be_rendered() function: while the status appears to be 200, during testing, it throws a 500 (internal server error). Oddly, the login page functions properly, leaving me a bit puzzled about the next steps, especially since I'm still new to Laravel.
 ` PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ that true is true

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Auth\AuthenticationTest
  ⨯ login screen can be rendered                                         0.44s  
  ✓ users can authenticate using the login screen                        0.05s  
  ✓ users can not authenticate with invalid password                     0.23s  
  ✓ users can logout                                                     0.03s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Auth\EmailVerificationTest
  ⨯ email verification screen can be rendered                            0.08s  
  ✓ email can be verified                                                0.03s  
  ✓ email is not verified with invalid hash                              0.03s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Auth\PasswordConfirmationTest
  ⨯ confirm password screen can be rendered                              0.08s  
  ✓ password can be confirmed                                            0.03s  
  ✓ password is not confirmed with invalid password                      0.23s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Auth\PasswordResetTest
  ⨯ reset password link screen can be rendered                           0.09s  
  ✓ reset password link can be requested                                 0.04s  
  ⨯ reset password screen can be rendered                                0.10s  
  ✓ password can be reset with valid token                               0.05s  

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Auth\PasswordUpdateTest
  ✓ password can be updated                                              0.04s  
  ✓ correct password must be provided to update password                 0.03s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Auth\RegistrationTest
  ⨯ registration screen can be rendered                                  0.10s  
  ✓ new users can register                                               0.03s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ⨯ the application returns a successful response                        0.08s  

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ProfileTest
  ⨯ profile page is displayed                                            0.12s  
  ✓ profile information can be updated                                   0.03s  
  ✓ email verification status is unchanged when the email address is un… 0.03s  
  ✓ user can delete their account                                        0.03s  
  ✓ correct password must be provided to delete account                  0.03s  
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\Auth\AuthenticationTest > login screen can be rende…   
  Expected response status code [200] but received 500.
Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200.

  at tests/Feature/Auth/AuthenticationTest.php:17
     13▕     public function test_login_screen_can_be_rendered(): void
     14▕     {
     15▕         $response = $this->get('/login');
     16▕ 
  ➜  17▕         $response->assertStatus(200);
     18▕     }
     19▕ 
     20▕     public function test_users_can_authenticate_using_the_login_screen(): void
     21▕     {````




I attempted to debug the issue, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any clues or errors.
  
  

`public function test_login_screen_can_be_rendered(): void
         {
             $response = $this->get('/login');
      dd($response);
           $response->assertStatus(200);
 }`


